# About the proof of the Four Vertex Theorem of Do Carmo.

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation

I have problems understanding this part of the proof given by Manfredo Do Carmo in *Differential Geometry of Curves* for the theorem of **The Four-Vertex Theorem**. I understand that in the first part he considers that exists a maximum and a minimum just because the parametrization of the curve is a mapping from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$. The next part is the one that I don't understand; he considers a line $L$ through those vertices where are the max and min of the curve, then he says this:

> Let $Ax + By + C = 0$ be the equation of $L$. If there are no further
>   vertices, $k'(s)$ keeps a constant sign on each of the arcs $\beta$ and $\gamma$ (until here, I understand it). We can then arrange the sign of all the coefficients $A, B, C$ so that the integral in Eq. (5)
>   is positive. This contradiction shows that there is a third vertex and that
>   $k'(s)$ changes sign on $\beta$ or $\gamma$, say, on $\beta$. Since $p$ and $q$ are points of maximum and minimum, $k'(s)$ changes sign twice on $p$. Thus, there is a fourth vertex.

The integral he refferes as Eq.(5) is:

$$\int_0^l (Ax+By+C)\frac{dk}{ds}ds=0$$

So I don't know how It would become a positive integral if it's zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point here is that we're trying to arrive at a contradiction when we assume that there are just two vertices (critical points of $k$). On one of the arcs we have $Ax+By+C>0$ and $k'(s)>0$ except at the endpoints. On the other arc, $Ax+By+C<0$ and $k'(x)<0$ except at the endpoints. Thus, the integral (5) is positive. On the other hand, by integration by parts, we see that the integral (5) is zero. This contradiction shows that there must be at least one more critical point of $k$, hence at least two more. (If you want to see the proof written out a little bit differently, feel free to look at my [differential geometry text](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf).)

Comment: Why it can't happen that on one of the arcs $Ax+By+C>0$ and $k'(s)<0$ and $Ax+By+C<0$ and $k'(s)>0$?

Comment: The main idea is that if $k'(s)$ doesn't have another point where $k'(s)=0$, the integral won't be zero because the integral will have the same sign in the interval?

Comment: He chose the signs on $A,B,C$ to make the signs line up. On each arc, both $Ax+By+C$ and $k'$ have constant sign.

Comment: @TedShifrin  In case you're still interested in this question, I have the same question and am still confused.  Surely A,B,C, all constants, can't be changed between the two arcs, unless dC is dividing the integral into 2 loops, where the L segment is a part of each loop?  But then there are clearly discontinuities in k at p and q.  And since A,B,C represents L, and not just an arbitrary line, it's not clear to me that we can set the signs as dC says in the first place!  BTW, the link you gave is not active.  Another available?  Thanks much!

Comment: @TedShifrin  BTW, did a duck duck go search and found a new link to your book.  I think your explanation on p. 29 is very clear.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, @bob.sacamento, I updated the link — the university treat us retired faculty like peons :P  Note that the two arcs of the curve are on opposite sides of $L$, as I said in my answer, so $Ax+By+Cz$ changes sign, as does $k'$.

Comment: @TedShifrin  Hey, if it was respect you wanted, you should have been in university administration!  :-)  Thanks again!

Comment: @iam_agf, multiplying $Ax+By+C=0$ by $-1$ gives another normal $(-a,-b)$ for the line, so you can really choose the direction such that the when values of $x,y$ are such that $ax+by+c>0$ that the derivative of the curvature is positive, and when $ax+by+c < 0$, the derivative of the curvature is negative, making the integral positive.